# How to detect konami code with Rx.js (reactive extensions for javascript)?

Tags: reactive-extensions-js

I want to start learning [Rx.js](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) and I'm looking for a cool example to start the ball rolling. How do I detect [konami code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) with Rx.js?

I want to detect a sequence of key press events (up up down down left right left right B A) and display an image if this happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my version:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rx.jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="result"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var konami = $(document).toObservable("keyup").Select(function(e) {
            return e.keyCode
        }).SkipWhile(function(k) {
            return (k != 38)
        }).BufferWithCount(
            10
        ).Where(function(ks) {
            return ks.length == 10 &&
                ks[0] == 38 && ks[1] == 38 &&
                ks[2] == 40 && ks[3] == 40 &&
                ks[4] == 37 && ks[5] == 39 &&
                ks[6] == 37 && ks[7] == 39 &&
                ks[8] == 66 && ks[9] == 65
        })

        var konamisub = konami.Subscribe(function(e) {
            $("#result").text("KONAMI!")
            $("#result").fadeIn().fadeOut()
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I convert the stream of keyup events into a stream of keycodes with the `Select`, then ignoring keypresses until the user press up (keycode 38) with the `SkipWhile`, then collecting 10 keystrokes with the `BufferWithCount`, then checking the keystrokes with the `Where`.

I tried using BufferWithTime, but it tends to cut in the middle of keystrokes.

If somebody can suggest improvements, I would love to hear them.

Comment: [This Rx.js Konami code example on github looks to be idiomatic](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/konamicode/konamicode.js). Looks like they're using conventional JS function naming now (no initial upper-case).

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to spoil the answer for you since you're learning, but I would try to think of the problem as, "How can I transform the Key up event into **the sequence** of the last 10 characters that were **recently** pressed", and compare that list to the constant list of "UUDDLRLRBA". (Hint: Buffer, Where, Select, Take, Repeat are your friends here)

Comment: Actually I don't mind spoilers :) but yes it wouldn't be as much fun. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I got it working, but it doesn't use `Take` nor `Repeat`. How would you use Take and Repeat in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

To update the answer from Endy (in RxJS 7) (with sequenceEqual from rxjs sample, because, smart usage of it :D)

```ts
const table: {[key: string]: number} = {
    ArrowUp: 38,
    ArrowDown: 40,
    ArrowLeft: 37,
    ArrowRight: 39,
    KeyB: 66,
    // Azerty compat
    KeyQ: 65,
    KeyA: 65,
};

const knownSequence = from([38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 66]);

const konami$ = fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(document, 'keyup').pipe(
    map((e) => table[e.code] ? table[e.code] : -1),
    skipWhile((k) => k !== 38),
    bufferCount(10, 1),
    mergeMap((x) => {
        return from(x).pipe(sequenceEqual(knownSequence));
    }),
    filter((sequenceEqual) => sequenceEqual),
    switchMap((_) => of('konami'))
);

// Basic usage (promisified)
await firstValueFrom(konami$);
// Do Konami thing
```